# The processEvent() method of Component class

Tags: java, event-handling, awt, event-listener

When handling various events, my general policy has been to create a `xxxHandler` class like `MouseHandler`, `WindowHandler`, etc which extends its appropriate `xxxAdapter` class provided by Java.

I was just going over some other text about handling events and it says that whenever you extend any `EventListener` interface, say `ActionListener`, you must call the `enableEvents(AWTEvent e)` method in the constructor and call the `super.processXXXEvent()` whenever an event is generated.

I find this approach highly confusing. These methods have the access specifier as `protected` so I assume that these are for internal use only ?

What exactly are those methods for ?

Are they really needed for handling events ?

Do they offer any benefits over the usual `actionPerformed()`, `mouseMoved()`, etc where you add your code to handle the events in the method definition without calling any `super` methods?

Help needed. Simple words are highly appreciated rather than technical mumbo-jumbo.

Comment: *"I was just going over some other text about handling events"*  Where did you see that?  Link or reference please.

Comment: `enableEvent` I don't find methods like this, only `enableEvents`

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry, I was  just sifting some websites for more info on handling events. It is highly unlikely that I will find that site again.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov my bad at the mistake there. Will correct it right away

Comment: I think those are internal methods as you said to process and deliver events, and they are not supposed and cannot to be used directly.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Yeah, they are I guess. Isn't it a waste if you create a class to handle `ActionEvent`s by implementing `ActionListener` and you have to specify that this must listen for `ActionEvent`s ?

Comment: Waste of what? This is widely adopted and recommended method.

Comment: I meant to say that if you implement `ActionListener` you are automatically listening for `ActionEvents`. It would be a waste if you had to call the `processEvents()` method.

Comment: It looks like the text has conflated a couple of ideas the `Event producer` calls `processXXXXEvent` which will call the `listener.handleXXXXEvent`. The `Listener` just does it's own thing. It is also the `Event producer` which will call `enableEvents`

Comment: @BevynQ these methods are used behind the scenes or need to be explicitly called ?

Comment: @Little Child : If you create your own component that extends `AWT` components then you need to activate events as `AWT` interacts with the underlying system. If you create a component that is not related to 'AWT' then it is good practice to follow the pattern but not necessary. If you are just creating listeners all you have to do is add the listener to the component it is listening to everything else is handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly are those methods for?

The `processEvent()` method filters the types of events that comes to it. The parameter to this method is of type `AWTEvent` type.
After filtering, this method calls the corresponding `processXYZEvent()` method which takes the corresponding event object.

For example, `processMouseEvent(MouseEvent)`

The `processXYZEvent()` method notifies the corresponding listeners about the event by passing the event object to the handler.

For example, `processMouseEvent(MouseEvent)` notifies the registered mouse listener(s).

The `enableEvents()` method decides what event(s) to give to the `processEvent()` method. This method cannot be overrided since it is final. However this can be accessed in the sub class of the `Component` class to decide what type of events that the component support.

> Are they really needed for handling events ?

Their role is mentioned above. This means that they are needed for handling events because you can only handle an event when an event object is created and dispatched and those methods do this.